# Insert Duplicates Of Distinct Value In One SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

The following is a sample INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Foo (c1,c2)
VALUES
    (a,1)
    ,(b,2)
    ,(c,3)
```

How do I insert these values to show the following result without redundant insert statements?:

```
c1 | c2
-------
a  |1
a  |1
a  |1
a  |1
a  |1
a  |1
b  |2
b  |2
b  |2
b  |2
b  |2
b  |2
c  |3
c  |3
c  |3
c  |3
c  |3
c  |3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to replicate your insert x times:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = replicate('
INSERT INTO 
    Foo (c1,c2)
VALUES
    (''a'',1)
    ,(''b'',2)
    ,(''c'',3)',6)

exec(@sql)

select * from Foo order by c1,c2
```

Alternatively, you can loop until you have the number of desired inserts:

```
while (select count(*) from Foo where c1 = 'a') < 6
    begin
        INSERT INTO 
            Foo (c1,c2)
        VALUES
            ('a',1)
            ,('b',2)
            ,('c',3)
    end

select * from Foo order by c1,c2
```

And yet another option would be:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Foo (c1,c2)
        VALUES
            ('a',1)
            ,('b',2)
            ,('c',3)
GO 6
```

Answer (score 1):

After inserting those values use `Recursive CTE` to do this

```
;with cte as
(
select c1,c2,1 as id from foo
union all
select c1,c2,id+1 from cte where id<5
)
Insert into Foo (c1,c2)
select c1,c2 from cte
```

Or do a `Cross Join` with `numbers` table. If you don't have `numbers` table use `master.dbo.spt_values` table

```
Insert into Foo(c1,c2)
SELECT c1, c2
FROM Foo
CROSS JOIN (SELECT number
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 5) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Impossible as designed! Two columns will not suffice. You need a child table or a third column to hold your "count". The number of rows for "a", "b", "c" cannot be inferred by two columns and less than the actual number of rows for each.